Closed-form solution to linear regression under positive semi-definite constraint
Let $X,Y\in \mathbb{R}^{d\times n}$ and $W\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$.
Is there a closed-form solution to the following minimization problem?
$$\min_W \|WX - Y\|_F^2, \quad W  \succeq 0.$$

There is a closed-form solution if $\,YX^{\bf+}\succeq0.\;$But in general, you'll need to use a numerical method.
One such method is gradient descent. Substitute $W=A^TA$ (the form of which guarantees that $W$ is positive semi-definite), then optimize wrt $A$.
The gradient $G$ of the objective function $\phi$ can be calculated as
$$\eqalign{
\def\p{\partial}
Z &= (\color{red}{W}X-Y) \;=\; (\color{red}{A^T\!A}X-Y) \\
\phi &= \tfrac12\big\|Z\big\|_F^2 \;\implies\;
\frac{\p\phi}{\p A} = A(ZX^T+XZ^T) \;\equiv\; G \\
}$$
Then starting with $\,k=0,\,A_k=I,\,$ iterate until convergence is obtained
$$\eqalign{
Z_k &= A_k^TA_kX-Y \\
G_k &= A_k(Z_kX^T+XZ_k^T) \\
A_{k+{\tt1}} &= A_k - \lambda_k G_k \\
k &= k + {\tt1} \\
}$$
The steplength can either be fixed
$\left({\rm e.g.}\;\lambda_k=10^{-2}\right)$ or dynamically
adjusted between iterations.

Thank you for your kind explanation!
